# Is there a formula for this interest over a period

Tags: numerical-methods

Say I have £100 overdraft and my balance is currently £0. when I go into my overdraft I am charged 1.25 % at the end of each day, but I have to divide the rest of the money equally for the next 10 days to see what I can realistically afford.

Is there a way formula to work out the most optimum daily spend for each day without trial and error?

for example, if 0% was deducted each day, clearly £10 each day would be optimal leaving you with `-£100`

[image: balance 0 -10 -20 -30 -40 -50 -]

with interest being deducted each day it would make this harder to work out

[image]

the point is trying to work out, how much money someone can afford to spend each day, if it was an equal amount through to the last day

Comment: It would probably matter whether $1.25\%$ is deducted at the *beginning* of the day or at the *end* of the day (after you've spent some). Also, I don't know what it means "most optimum". If you are after spending all money, and as much as possible, I would spend all I can on the first day and not let anything be eaten up by the interest. It is a different question "how much should you spend each day if you are spending the same amount each day".

Comment: Your problem does not seem correctly specified. If interest is deducted, it is obviously better to spend the whole on the first day. (I also agree with Golden_Ratio below.)

Comment: Please explain "if 0% was deducted each day, clearly £10 each day would be optimal leaving you with £0"

Comment: It is also unclear if the interests are simple (1.25£ a day) or compound. Please explain the rule.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I have corrected the question, its basically an overdraft question, no wonder it didn't make sense sorry! So taking all money out on day one would incur the most interest in this case as you would be going over your overdraft

Answer (score 2):

Let the number of days be $D=10$, the total money available be $M=100$, and the interest fee be $r=0.0125$. The daily spending is $s$. The total money spent after $D$ days is
\begin{align*}
M & =\bigg(\Big(\big(s(1+r)+s\big)(1+r)+s\Big)+\cdots\bigg)(1+r) \\
  & = s(1+r)^{D} + s(1+r)^{D-1} + \cdots + s(1+r) \\
  & = s\frac{(1+r)^{D+1} - (1+r)}{r}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the optimal daily spending is
\begin{equation*}
s=\frac{Mr}{(1+r)^{D+1} - (1+r)}
\end{equation*}
which in your case is $s=9.33363693543$.

Answer (score 1):

Say the amount of money I have at day $0$ is $M_0$. Over the course of $N$ days, I want to spend an equal amount of money $f$ each day such that at the end of the $N$ days, I have $0$ left. However, each day after I spent my money, I loose a certain amount $x$ of money. What is the value of $f$ ?

The case $x=0$ is already taken care, so let us consider that $x\neq 0$

We can write a sequence corresponding to our problem:

  -day
  $0$
  :
  $M_0$
  -day $1$: $M_1 = (M_0-f) - x(M_0-f) = (1-x)(M_0-f)$
  -...
  -day $N$: $M_N = (1-x)(M_{N-1}-f) = (1-x)M_{N-1} - f(1-x)$

This sequence can be solved and we find:
\begin{equation}
M_N = M_0(1-x)^N + f \frac{1-x}{x}[(1-x)^N - 1].
\end{equation}
At the end of the $N$ days, we want $M_N=0$, such that it can be solved for $f$, we have:
\begin{equation}
f=-M_0 \frac{x(1-x)^{N-1}}{(1-x)^N - 1}
\end{equation}

If the money is taken before we can spend some, the sequence is a little bit modified:

  -day
  $0$
  :
  $M_0$
  -day $1$: $M_1 = (1-x)M_0 - f$
  -...
  -day $N$: $M_N = (1-x)M_{N-1} - f$

Again solving the sequence gives:
\begin{equation}
M_N = M_0(1-x)^N + f \frac{1}{x}[(1-x)^N - 1].
\end{equation}
At the end of the $N$ days, we want $M_N=0$, such that it can be solved for $f$, we have:
\begin{equation}
f=-M_0 \frac{x(1-x)^{N}}{(1-x)^N - 1}
\end{equation}

For the specific example asked, we have $N=10$, $x=1.25\%$ and $M_0=100$, we can compute:
\begin{align}
f_{after} \approx 9.4435\\
f_{before} \approx 9.3255
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you withdraw $x$ every day.

At the end of day 1, your overdraft is $x\times1.0125$.

At the end of day 2, your overdraft is $(x\times1.0125+x)\times1.0125$
$$=x\times(1.0125+1.0125^2)$$

Continuing this pattern, at the end of day $10$, your overdraft is $$x\times(1.0125+1.0125^2+...+1.0125^{10})$$

The bracketed term is a geometric series whose sum is $$1.0125\left(\frac{1.0125^{10}-1}{1.0125-1}\right)$$

Your overdraft is $100$ and this equals the above expression, so $$x=\frac{100\times0.0125}{1.0125(1.0125^{10}-1)}=9.33363...$$